# Why doesn't the frequency of a strategy reach zero under the replicator dynamics?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, game-theory

**Background**
The replicator equation with $n$ strategies is given by the differential equation:
\begin{equation}
  \dot x_{i} = x_{i} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_{j} - \phi \right)
  \qquad i = 1, \ldots, n
\end{equation}
where $x_i$ is the frequency of the strategy $i$, $A=[a_{ij}]$ is the payoff matrix, and $\phi$ is the average fitness of the population.

**Question**: According to books on game theory (e.g., Nowak's "Evolutionary Dynamics"), if $x_i\neq 0$ at some time, $x_i$ might converge to zero but it will never reach zero. Why is that?

Comment: In what sense " $x_i$ will never reach zero " ? Even asymptotically? Or you mean only at finite moment of time?

Comment: Because of the uniqueness theorem for solutions of ODE.

Comment: @Evgeny x_i can asymptotically approach zero. I updated my question to make this point more clear.

Comment: Extending @Artem 's comment, I'll add only one thing: coordinate planes are flow invariant.

Comment: @Artem My understanding is that, for a game with two strategies, the uniqueness theorem says that there is exactly one solution curve in $R^2$ passing through a given point $(a_1, a_2)$. Why does this prevent $x_1$ (or $x_2$) from reaching zero?

Comment: @falsum Because both points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are solutions as well!

Comment: @Artem I think I got it. Because the solutions are unique, the solution curves cannot intersect each other.